# Can't manage to test rest template helper class

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, testing, spock

I'm trying for more than an hour to test this class. It went so ugly of stubbing the whole components of the method etc. I'd love some advice how to make a better test or refactor the class to make it way easier to test. I could not figure out a way yet.

**Class to Test**

```
@Slf4j
public final class HistoryRestService {
  static RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

  public static Optional<List<History>> findLatestHistories() {
    String url = buildUrl();
    ResponseEntity<History[]> responseEntity = null;
    try {
      responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, History[].class);
    } catch (ResourceAccessException e) {
      log.warn("No connection to History persistence. Please check if the history persistence started up properly");
      return Optional.empty();
    }
    History[] histories = responseEntity.getBody();
    return Optional.of(Arrays.asList(histories));
  }

  private static String buildUrl() {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder.append("http://");
    stringBuilder.append("localhost");
    stringBuilder.append(":8081");
    stringBuilder.append("/history/get");
    return stringBuilder.toString();
  }

  // For Testing
  static void setRestTemplate(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
    HistoryRestService.restTemplate = restTemplate;
  }
}
```

**Spock Test which fails**

```
class HistoryRestServiceTest extends Specification {
    def "test findLatestHistories"() {
        given:
        History mockedHistory = Mock()
        HistoryRestService uut = new HistoryRestService()
        History[] expected = [mockedHistory]
        RestTemplate mockedRestTemplate = Stub()
        ResponseEntity<History> mockedResponseEntity = Stub()

        mockedResponseEntity.getBody() >> expected
        mockedRestTemplate.getForEntity(_) >> mockedResponseEntity

        uut.setRestTemplate(mockedRestTemplate)

        when:
        def actual  = uut.findLatestHistories()
        then:
        actual.get() == expected

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using real depedency-injection (spring/guice/cdi) instead of static variables.

Furthermore, you should think about what you want to test, is it the correct request and parsing of the network call, then write an integration test using something like [mockserver](http://www.mock-server.com/) or [wiremock](http://wiremock.org/) to have the whole stack. Or, if you are just concerned with the result handling, then you could move the code that interacts with `RestTemplate` into a separate method and use [partial mocking](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1/all_in_one.html#PartialMocks) to mock this method. I'd suggest to use the real integration test, but for the sake of an example this should work, but I didn't verify the code.

```
@Slf4j
public class HistoryRestService {
  private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

  public HistoryRestService() {
     restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
  }

  public HistoryRestService(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
     this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
  }

  public Optional<List<History>> findLatestHistories() {
    try {
      return Optional.of(Arrays.asList(getLatestHistories(buildUrl())));
    } catch (ResourceAccessException e) {
      log.warn("No connection to History persistence. Please check if the history persistence started up properly");
      return Optional.empty();
    }
  }

  History[] getLatestHistories(String url) throws {
    ResponseEntity<History[]> responseEntity = null;
    responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, History[].class);
    return responseEntity.getBody()
  }

  private String buildUrl() {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder.append("http://");
    stringBuilder.append("localhost");
    stringBuilder.append(":8081");
    stringBuilder.append("/history/get");
    return stringBuilder.toString();
  }
}


class HistoryRestServiceTest extends Specification {
    @Subject
    HistoryRestService uut = Spy()

    def "test findLatestHistories"() {
        given:
        History[] expected = [mockedHistory]

        when:
        def actual  = uut.findLatestHistories()

        then:
        actual.get() == expected
        1 * uut.getLatestHistories(_ as String) >> expected
    }

    def "test findLatestHistories returns empty on exceptions"() {
        given:
        History[] expected = [mockedHistory]

        when:
        def actual  = uut.findLatestHistories()

        then:
        !actual.present
        1 * uut.getLatestHistories(_ as String) >> {throw new ResourceAccessException()}
    }
}
```